# Upgrading exp-resso store from 1.5.3 to 1.6.0

Tags: expressionengine, expresso-store

Anyone having problems with upgrading Store from 1.5.3 to 1.6.0 ?

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: register_member
Filename: store/mod.store.php
Line Number: 463

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: username
Filename: store/mod.store.php
Line Number: 474

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: screen_name
Filename: store/mod.store.php
Line Number: 474

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: password
Filename: store/mod.store.php
Line Number: 474

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: password_confirm
Filename: store/mod.store.php
Line Number: 474
```

Errors above started propping up on check out pages after the upgrade.

Comment: @Cem can you try clearing your cart? It might just be an issue with the new checkout fields in 1.6.

Comment: Also have you definitely run the standard upgrade script under Add-ons > Modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to try:

- Make sure you have run the upgrade script under **Add-ons > Modules > Run Module Updates**
- Try opening a different browser. If this solves the problem, then it's probably session related. Emptying your `exp_store_carts` table should fix this for all customers.
- Try deleting and re-uploading all the files for this module. Then run the update as above.

As a last resort, you could also try completely uninstalling and re-installing the module.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, emptying your exp_store_carts table fixed the errors but now add to cart is not functioning. it rather refreshes the page.     I have also upgraded to 1.6.1 with Run Module Updates applied.

Comment: Is your product out of stock? Are you using any fancy JS? Do the example templates work? Probably best to start a new question with as much info as possible so we can help.

Comment: Products are not out of stock, not fancy JS, example templates are having the same issue as well.